# Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml

I am trying to pass parameters to one of the nested stacks by populating the values from another nested stacks output.

**And i do not want any cross-referencing (unless there is no way around it)**

The idea is pretty straight forward.

```
RootStack

-NstdStackVPC
-NstdStackSG
-NstdStackEC2
```

The problem is on the last nested stack while creating EC2.
If i created the resource in the root stack directly the EC2 gets created

```
Description: RootStack
Parameters:
 MyKeyName:
  Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  Default: my-test-key
 EC2ImageId:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
  Default: ami-0dxxxxa

Resources:
 NstdStackVPC ......
 NstdStackSG ......

 EC2Host: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
   SubnetId: !GetAtt NstdStackVPC.Outputs.VPCPubSubnet
   ImageId: !Ref EC2ImageId
   InstanceType: t2.micro
   KeyName: !Ref MyKeyName
   SecurityGroupIds: 
   - !GetAtt NstdStackSG.Outputs.SecGrp4EC2Host
```

But if i try to create the EC2 as a nested stack

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: NstdStackEC2.
Parameters:
 myNstdKeyName:
  Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
 myNstdImageId:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
 myNstdSecGrp:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
 myNstdEC2HostSubnet:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id

Resources:
 EC2Host: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
   SubnetId: !Ref myNstdEC2HostSubnet
   ImageId: !Ref myNstdImageId
   InstanceType: t2.micro
   KeyName: !Ref myNstdKeyName
   SecurityGroupIds:
    - Ref myNstdSecGrp
```

By changing the root stack as follows

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: RootStack
Parameters:
 MyKeyName:
  Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  Default: my-test-key
 EC2ImageId:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
  Default: ami-0dxxxxa

Resources:
 NstdStackVPC ......
 NstdStackSG ......
 NstdStackEC2:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
   TemplateURL: https://bkt.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/NstdEC2Host.yml
   Parameters:
    myNstdKeyName: !Ref MyKeyName
    myNstdImageId: !Ref EC2ImageId
    myNstdSecGrp: !GetAtt NstdStackSG.Outputs.SecGrp4BasHost
    myNstdEC2HostSubnet: !GetAtt NstdStackVPC.Outputs.VPCPubSubnet
```

It gives me the following error:
**Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties**

tried removing all the parameters to try one by one. But it fails on everything.
Even for the parameters that are being referenced directly from the root stack i.e., MyKeyName, EC2ImageId

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same exact error message with a similar problem and solution. I came here and since the issue was slightly different, this question helped me get to my solution. So, not trying to hijack this question, simply hoping to provide what I found additionally useful to the next person visiting.

I was nesting a cluster template very similar to [this one](https://github.com/widdix/aws-cf-templates/tree/master/ecs) and OPs example. Passing Subnets as a list of strings (I believe List<AWS::Some::Type> will also work).

```
Subnets:
  Description: Subnets of the of the cluster availaibility zone
  Type: CommaDelimitedList
  Default: subnet-0d..de,subnet-0e..7a,subnet-0b..24
```

And I'm using the above parameters to call the partial child template as follows.

```
ECS:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    TemplateURL: https://xx.amazonaws.com/yy/zz.yaml
    Parameters:
      SecurityGroups: !Join [",", [!GetAtt SecurityGroups.Outputs.ECSHostSecurityGroup]]
      Subnets: !Join [",", !Ref Subnets]
```

So, In the above example, the SecurityGroups are joined together into a list from the output of the SecurityGroup Nested Template, but the subnets are simply joined together from the comma delimited parameter. There is a [knowledge-center article too](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-parameters-nested-stacks/), if you want more info. TA OP

Comment: I had a very similar issue, but I feed in comma separated string list (`StringList`) from SSM parameters. I just could not figure out why the SSM `StringList` value, read as `CommaDelimitedList` CFT root stack parameter cannot be accepted when I pass it on to a nested stack, that also expects a `CommaDelimitedList` parameter. Your solution with the `!Join` just worked a treat, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally sorted this out myself.

In my NstdStackSG outputs section i was referring to the object itself.
And that is where this goes wrong.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Security group nested stack
Resources:
 MySecGrp
  Type: ....
  .....
  ....
Outputs:
 MyOtptSecGrp:
#This one is working for me.
  Value: !GetAtt MySecGrp.GroupId
#previously i was assigning the following value
  #Value: !Re MySecGrp
```

And now in the RootStack

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: RootStack
Parameters:
 MyKeyName:
  Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
  Default: my-test-key
 EC2ImageId:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id
  Default: ami-0dxxxxa
Resources:
 NstdStackVPC ......
 NstdStackSG ......
 NstdStackEC2:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
   TemplateURL: https://bkt.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/NstdEC2Host.yml
   Parameters:
    myNstdKeyName: !Ref MyKeyName
    myNstdImageId: !Ref EC2ImageId
    myNstdSecGrp: !GetAtt NstdStackSG.Outputs.SecGrp4BasHost
    myNstdEC2HostSubnet: !GetAtt NstdStackVPC.Outputs.VPCPubSubnet
```

And in my nestedEC2Stack

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: NstdStackEC2

Parameters:
 myNstdSecGrp:
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id
 myNstdEC2HostSubnet:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
 myNstdKeyName:
  Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
 myNstdImageId:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Image::Id

Resources:

 EC2Host: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
   SubnetId: !Ref myNstdEC2HostSubnet
   ImageId: !Ref myNstdImageId
   InstanceType: t2.micro
   KeyName: !Ref myNstdKeyName
   SecurityGroupIds:
    - !Ref myNstdSecGrp
```

Hope this helps. (If not in solving then at least in pointing the right direction)